# org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /JSP/BillingPayment.jsp(15,3) No tag "ajax" defined in tag library imported with prefix "f"

Tags: jsf-2

Have some doubt with JSF 2, I would like to use the ajax functionality of JSF 2 only, not going to use any of its implementations.

Have taken the JSF libraries from http://download.java.net/maven/2/com/sun/faces/jsf-api/2.1.1-b03/

But still none of these are supporting the ajax tag that I am using to implement the functionality.

I get the error 
**org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /JSP/BillingPayment.jsp(15,3) No tag "ajax" defined in tag library imported with prefix "f"**
for the following request.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<html>
<body>
<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid>
        <h:inputText value="#{dataTableBean.sponsorID}">
            <f:ajax event="keyup" />
        </h:inputText>
        <h:outputText id="text" value="#{dataTableBean.sponsorID}" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

For this I presume, I am not having the proper library, please can you give me the correct JSF2 library that supports ajax.

Comment: **MY JSP** `<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%> <%@ taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%> <html> <body> <h:form> <h:panelGrid> <h:inputText value="#{dataTableBean.sponsorID}"> <f:ajax event="keyup" /> </h:inputText> <h:outputText id="text" value="#{dataTableBean.sponsorID}" /> </h:panelGrid> </h:form> </body> </html> `

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you still prefer the legacy JSP over its superios successor Facelets?

Comment: the current system is in JSP, we are redesigning it wid JSF , so am currently in to giving a POC , analysing how efficient is JSF and how well it fits our app.

Comment: but can you tell me why none of the JSF2 library IMPL/CORE tld is not having the ajax tag?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Facelets Technology. Your `sth.xhtml` will have this form

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></meta>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my.css" />
</h:head>
<h:body>
</h:body>
</html>
```

If you are using netbeans ide 7.1 when you are creating a jsf page check the faceletes option.
I had a similar question
[h:outputScript not defined in library h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443803/houtputscript-not-defined-netbeans).

Answer (score 0):

Your link points to the **jsf-api.jar**. You need **jsf-impl.jar** as well which you can find in [this directory](http://download.java.net/maven/2/com/sun/faces/jsf-impl/).

If you have both in your classpath, you should be able to access the TLDs. I think there's no way to use jsf without a jsf-impl.jar.

Furthermore, you have to include all components tags on your page with the `f:view` tag. So your page should have the following structure:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>

<f:view>
 <html>
  <body>
    <h:form>
      <h:panelGrid>
        <h:inputText value="#{dataTableBean.sponsorID}">
          <f:ajax event="keyup" />
        </h:inputText>
        <h:outputText id="text" value="#{dataTableBean.sponsorID}" />
      </h:panelGrid>
   </h:form>
  </body>
 </html>
</f:view>
```

Comment: yes have taken JSF impl also, jsut for reference from where I have taken, gave the path.

Comment: Thanks Matt, still getting the error - not sure why those tld's are not having ajax element

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /JSP/BillingPayment.jsp(12,4) No tag "ajax" defined in tag library imported with prefix "f"