# h:outputScript not defined in library h

Tags: jsp, jsf, jsf-2

I enetered this code

```
<h:outputScript name="jsf.js" library="javax.faces" target="head"/>
```

But my IDE says that `<h:outputScript>` tag is not defined in library `h` which I declared as below.

```
<%@taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
```

What's going on?

Comment: Please add the header of your page, especially the part where the xml namespaces are defined.

Comment: <head><meta http-equiv="Contenet-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8849-7"><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="my.css"/></head>

Comment: The xmlns part of the html tag is more interesting.

Comment: And please put all new information into your question using the "edit" button. Thanks.

Comment: you mean <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">Sorry i am new to programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSF 2.0 `<h:head>`, `<h:body>`, `<h:outputScript>`, `<h:outputStylesheet>`, `<f:ajax>` and all `<ui:xxx>` tags are **not** available when you use the ancient JSP as view technology. You should instead be using its successor Facelets, which is usually a XHTML file.

JSP has been **deprecated** as JSF view technology since 2009 already. Make sure you're reading up to date resources when learning JSF. Start at [our JSF wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info).

#### See also:

- [Java EE 6 tutorial - Introduction to Facelets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepx.html)
- [Why Facelets is preferred over JSP as the view definition language from JSF2.0 onwards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092161/why-facelets-is-preferred-over-jsp-as-the-view-definition-language-from-jsf2-0-o)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your xml name space definitions are correct. To include JSF tag libs you normally need the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

   <!-- header and body of your page -->

</html>
```

Comment: I think its correct <%@taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%> <%@taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>

Comment: I found the solution. Thanks for your help.The solution was that when i created the new jsf page i had to select in the opti0ns tab the Facelets option.