# JSF or JSP 2 Tag Files for new project

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jsf, rich-ui

I have a requirement to amalgamate functionality from some parked  Java side-projects into a new application and am trying to make a decision on some of the third-party libraries to use, specifically relating to the UI.  I would be very interested to get some feedback from tech arch oriented members on their views in relation to recent java framework trends and experiences.

The legacy projects are a mixed-bunch, all web-based, lots of business logic around CRUDable objects with searches. One uses an in-house framework - very fast, scalable, but with the disadvantages associated with in-house work - learning curve for new devs etc.  Another, a Tapestry 5 app - very robust, terrific integration with XFire / CXF for generating web services, rapid UI generation, but with a good learning curve for non-Tapestry types.  The third, a Spring 3 app, using JSP 2.0 Tag Files for view layer, with some sprinklings of JQuery for presentation / ajax.

I'm very familiar with Spring and find tag files for the UI with Tiles very effective in terms of low-complexity and performance.  I have also recently wrapped up a project that used RichFaces 4 which was successful and came in on time.  I like the rich UI that comes for free with RF / IceFaces etc., and have noticed that JSF in its more recent versions has retired JSP altogether.

To cut to the chase, is the restriction of using a component based UI library with clearly defined but unmodifiable behaviour like RF / IF a better fit for a new app than a roll-your-own solution, with tag files / JQuery.  I'm more familiar with the latter, but don't want to go down the wrong path at this early stage of a project by adopting an out of date approach.  I want to continue using Spring 3 Controllers for RESTful, bookmarkable application entry points - do IF / RF mix with Spring or does a JSF approach remove the MVC obligation completely from Spring?

If the MVC obligation is removed from Spring:

- how would the JSF lifecycle integrate with Spring - would it be self-contained and just use IOC for wiring Spring services?
- is there good integration with a IF / RF approach for generating web services etc.?
- what kind of support do IF / RF have for tablet / mobile?
- is Spring needed at all - would managed beans do the trick?

Comment: I tried to answer the core questions you were asking about JSF and Spring, but your question was overly broad so I felt I needed to remove certain parts of your question just to make it answerable.  I recommend posting seperate questions rather than have all of your thoughts in one single place.  You will get better answers that way and they are more likely to help future visitors.  Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow/faq) for more information.

Comment: @maple_shaft Thanks for the helpful details, and also for the pointer about Primefaces components for mobile applications - very impressive, and in general performance PF appears to stack up very well against RF / IF.  I am in a comfort-zone with Spring, but you have helped clarify the fact that JSF is fully capable of managing the MVC application aspects without Spring.

Comment: @maple_shaft Baked-in AJAX aside, have you found advantages in terms of productivity with the adoption of JSF?  My own experience has been that JSP 2 Tag Files were simple to use, and not overly verbose.  I have found the render lifecycle for JSF can cause confusion among developers and that it is not uncommon to find some initialization logic or other lengthy process being invoked several times during a page render.  Also, the xhtml files can get quite verbose. Are there any compelling reasons you can think of that warrant a move to JSF (apart from an Oracle recommendation)?

Comment: I like how it marries Ajax functionality and client state with server state and an event model. I struggled with it until I learned the concepts and fudamentals, now I am more productive with it than I was with Spring MVC.  There is a learning curve for new developers and there are some real performance issues if you are not careful.  I am comfortable with JSF and choose it now and have been doing some really awesome things with a very small team. Beyond my personal preference, I do not have a compelling reason for you to switch to JSF.

Comment: @maple_shaft Experience of higher productivity is compelling enough for me - thanks for your insights. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092161/why-facelets-is-preferred-over-jsp-as-the-view-definition-language-from-jsf2-0-o/) post is another convincing insight from an SO member whose insights I respect (and who originally turned me on to JSP 2 Tag Files in some older posts...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To cut to the chase, is the restriction of using a component based UI library with clearly defined but unmodifiable behaviour like RF / IF a better fit for a new app than a roll-your-own solution, with tag files / JQuery.

It is not one or the other.  Java Server Faces is a Component Based Web Framework that allows for the synchronization of server and client state on requests and responses to allow for things like a phase and event model in your applications.  Many JSF components utilize jQuery inherently and expand upon rich client controls by wrapping them in server side behavior.  It is not unmodifiable behavior by any stretch, just that there is a bit of a learning curve to customize things in a very specific way.

JSF is currently the Oracle recommended approach to Java EE web development.

> do IF / RF mix with Spring or does a JSF approach remove the MVC obligation completely from Spring?
>
> how would the JSF lifecycle integrate with Spring - would it be self-contained and just use IOC for wiring Spring services?

JSF is inherently its own MVC framework and with managed properties already has its own baked in Dependency Injection.  Core Spring is primarily Depedency Injection so one would think that they are at odds but surprisingly they go together well.

Recent versions of Spring have provided their own EL Resolver implementation for JSF that allows JSF Managed Beans to be handled as Spring beans.  This class can even be backfitted into older versions of Spring, which I have done and noticed no issues.

Spring MVC is primarily built on JSP technology, but it is not a core part of Spring.  You simply need not include it in a JSF web application if you don't wish to serve JSP pages.

> is there good integration with a IF / RF approach for generating web services etc.?

When it comes to web services in a JSF application it is best to remember that JSF doesn't have to define limitations on your web app, nor does it have to define it in its entirety.  JSF is merely the front end for JSF page requests.  Knowing this your same web application can also serve SOAP or REST based web services of their own, or simply handle these web services at data sources on the server side in your business logic.  Another way still is to call external web services from Javascript on your page.  Nothing in JSF precludes you from incorporating any element of HTML, Javascript or even newer HTML5 technology.

> what kind of support do IF / RF have for tablet / mobile?

Not sure what IF and RF have but I know that Primefaces has an impressive control set for mobile applications that is worth checking out.

> is Spring needed at all - would managed beans do the trick?

No absolutely it is not needed.  I happen to like Spring though so I use it.