# placeholder not recognized when using omnifaces

Tags: jsf, omnifaces

I'm new to JSF. Well, I'm trying  to pass attributes like placeholder through jsf with omnifaces. But somehow the attributes are not recognized. Am I missing something?

Omnifaces.jar is in the Java Server Faces library and I added the Html5RenderKitFactory to the faces-config.xml.

Here's what the content of the JSP file look like:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui">
<head>
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <f:view>
            <f:loadBundle basename="de.jsf.messages" var="msg" />

            <h:form styleClass="form-signin" o:autocomplete="off">
                <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                    <h:inputText value="#{user.name}" styleClass="input-block-level" placeholder="#{msg.user}">
```

I'm using Tomcat 7.0, MyFaces 2.1, Omnifaces 1.4.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing legacy JSP with its successor Facelets (XHTML). What you've there is a JSP file. JSP is **deprecated** since JSF 2.0 (released Dec 2009) and succeeded by Facelets (XHTML). JSF 2.0 compatible libraries do not have JSP tag libraries anymore and are incompatible with JSP. They are designed for usage with Facelets only.

Rename your `page.jsp` to `page.xhtml` and get rid of all `<%@ %>` things. This way PrimeFaces and OmniFaces will work and you'll also be able to use the new JSF 2.0 awesomeness such as `<h:head>` and `<f:ajax>`.

I'm not sure which resources you used while learning JSF, but the attempt to use JSP indicates that you were reading JSF 1.x targeted resources. This is not right when your intent is to learn JSF 2.x as many, many things have changed in JSF 2.x as compared to JSF 1.x. I strongly recommend to check twice if the resource is JSF 2.x targeted.

#### See also:

- [Why Facelets is preferred over JSP as the view definition language from JSF2.0 onwards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092161/why-facelets-is-preferred-over-jsp-as-the-view-definition-language-from-jsf2-0-o)
- [What are the main disadvantages of Java Server Faces 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623911/what-are-the-main-disadvantages-of-java-server-faces-2-0/3646940#3646940)
- [Migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0/)
- [Our JSF wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) - contains links to sane JSF 2.0 learning resources