# Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/core, but no tag was defined for name: ajax

Tags: ajax, jsp, jsf, jsf-2

Below page

```
<%@ taglib prefix="h" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="f" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" %>
<h:form>
    <h:outputLabel id="outtxt" value="#{user.name}"/>
    <h:inputText id="intxt" value="#{user.name}">
        <f:ajax event="keyup" execute="intxt" render="outtxt"/>
    </h:inputTtext>
</h:form>
```

Throws below error

> Tag Library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/core, but no tag was defined for name: ajax

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<f:ajax>` is only available in [Facelets tag library of JSF](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/).

However, you're using JSP which is [**deprecated**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepx.html) since JSF 2.0. All JSF 2.x development for JSP has stopped. All new JSF 2.x specific tags/attributes such as `<f:ajax>`, `<h:head>`, `<h:link>`, `<h:button>`, `<h:inputFile>`, `<f:viewParam>`, `<f:viewAction>`, etc are not available [in JSP tag library of JSF](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/jsp/). You need to migrate JSP to its successor Facelets in order to utilize the new JSF 2.x specific tags/attributes. See also below links for more detail about Facelets:

- [Our Facelets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/facelets/info)
- [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets/)
- [Migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0)
- [Why Facelets is preferred over JSP as the view definition language from JSF2.0 onwards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092161/why-facelets-is-preferred-over-jsp-as-the-view-definition-language-from-jsf2-0-o)

If you've found this JSP example in some JSF book/tutorial/resource, then it's likely a JSF 1.x targeted one. When learning JSF 2.x, make absolutely sure that you read a JSF 2.x targeted book/tutorial/resource. [Our JSF wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) is a good starting point.