# Can I use facelet using servlet for java web application?

Tags: java, servlets, jsf-2, facelets

I am using facelet and servlet so, is it possible to use facelet with servlet like jsp with servlet ?

and how much it is compitible and which one is better ?

Comment: Not sure why somebody vote to close this as too broad, when the answer is in the official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in [Java EE 6 Tutorial: Introduction to Facelets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giepx.html) (emphasys mine):

> The term Facelets refers to the view declaration language for **JavaServer Faces technology**. JavaServer Pages (JSP) technology, previously used as the presentation technology for JavaServer Faces, does not support all the new features available in JavaServer Faces in the Java EE 6 platform. JSP technology is considered to be a deprecated presentation technology for JavaServer Faces. **Facelets is a part of the JavaServer Faces specification** and also the preferred presentation technology for building **JavaServer Faces technology-based** applications.

As you can notice, Facelets works with JSF, not with plain servlets.

More info:

- [What is the difference between JSF, Servlet and JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2095397/1065197)
- [Why Facelets is preferred over JSP as the view definition language from JSF2.0 onwards?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13092161/1065197)
- [StackOverflow Facelets wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/facelets/info)