# Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://richfaces.ajax4jsf.org/rich"

Tags: eclipse, jsf, richfaces, jsf-2.2

I've been trying migrating my project from JSF 1.0 and RichFaces 3.1.4 to JSF 2.2 and RichFaces 4.5.2.

I want to keep the pages JSP formatted (is it even possible?)

While replacing the jars of RichFaces I get the following error:

> Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://richfaces.ajax4jsf.org/rich"

What is the cause to this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSP is **deprecated** since JSF 2.0. It's succeeded by Facelets (XHTML). Therefore, JSF 2.0 compatible component libraries like RichFaces 4+ and PrimeFaces 2+ do not support JSP anymore. Those component libraries do not contain JSP taglibs anymore. Hence this error.

Migrate JSP to its successor Facelets.

#### See also:

- [Migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0)
- [Why Facelets is preferred over JSP as the view definition language from JSF2.0 onwards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092161/why-facelets-is-preferred-over-jsp-as-the-view-definition-language-from-jsf2-0-o)