# Custom JSF component declared in .tld file works in JSP but not in Facelets

Tags: jsp, jsf, migration, facelets, taglib

I have a custom JSF component which is registered in a `.tld` file. It works fine in JSP when I declare it as below:

```
<%@taglib uri="http://example.com/ui" prefix="ex"%>
```

However, it doesn't work in Facelets when I try to declare as below:

```
<html xmlns:ex="http://example.com/ui">
```

How can I use my custom JSF component in Facelets too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSP and Facelets are entirely distinct view technologies. JSP is Servlet based while Facelets is XML based. You can't reuse tags/taglibs of the one on the other. What `*.tld` files for JSP are, are `*.taglib.xml` files for Facelets.

Here's a kickoff example of how a Facelets taglib file look like for JSF 2.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<facelet-taglib 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">

    <namespace>http://example.com/ui</namespace>

    <tag>
        <tag-name>foo</tag-name>
        <component>
            <component-type>com.example.Foo</component-type>
        </component>
    </tag>
</facelet-taglib>
```

If you have a component library in flavor of a JAR file, just drop it in its `/META-INF` folder. It will be auto-discovered. If you have however those custom components coupled in the WAR itself, then drop it in `/WEB-INF` folder and register it in `web.xml` via below context param:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/example-ui.taglib.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

If you indend to pick JSF 2.2 as a minimum requirement, update the taglib's root declaration as below:

```
<facelet-taglib
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">
```

#### See also:

- [Migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0/)
- [Mojarra's JSP to Facelets migration guide](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/rlnotes/2.0.0/migration.html)
- [Why Facelets is preferred over JSP as the view definition language from JSF2.0 onwards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092161/why-facelets-is-preferred-over-jsp-as-the-view-definition-language-from-jsf2-0-o/)

Noted should be that JSP is since 2009 deprecated as view technology for JSF. So if you intend to build a new custom component library, making it JSP compatible would be a complete waste of effort as no one sane JSF developer would use it. Moreover, practically all JSF 2.x component libraries don't support JSP (anymore).