# xmlns:ui tags doesn't render properly in a JSPX page

Tags: jsp, jsf, jsf-2, facelets

I have created a new JSF project in eclipse using apache myfaces-2.0.23 with trinidad tag library. My Login.jspx looks like below,

```
<jsp:root xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" 
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" version="2.0"
    xmlns:tr="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad"
    xmlns:trh="http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/html"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
   <jsp:directive.page language="java"
        contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" />
    <jsp:text>
        <![CDATA[ <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> ]]>
    </jsp:text>
    <jsp:text>
        <![CDATA[ <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> ]]>
    </jsp:text>
<ui:composition template="templates/templateLayout.jspx">
<f:view>
    <ui:define name="body">
        <tr:outputLabel value="User Name: "></tr:outputLabel>
        <tr:inputText required="true" value="#{login.userName}"></tr:inputText>
        <tr:spacer height="5"></tr:spacer>
        <tr:outputLabel value="Password: "></tr:outputLabel>
        <tr:inputText required="true" value="#{login.password}"></tr:inputText>
        <tr:spacer height="10"></tr:spacer>
        <tr:commandButton text="Login" action="#{loginAction.login}"></tr:commandButton>
    </ui:define>
</f:view>
</ui:composition>
</jsp:root>
```

When the application is deployed in JBoss and run, I am able to see the text boxes and button. However the templateLayout contents are not displayed!

When I source in browser, the ui:composition tag is just rendered as is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 

         <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
    **<ui:composition** template="templates/templateLayout.jspx"><ui:define name="onPageLoadJavascript"/><ui:defin`enter code here`e name="pageSpecificJavascript"/><ui:define name="body">........................................................
```

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is that you created a legacy JSPX page instead of a modern Facelets (XHTML) page. The `<ui:xxx>` tags work only in Facelets (like as that `<jsp:xxx>` tags work only in JSP(X)). Moreover, JSF 2.x compatible component libraries like PrimeFaces 2+ and RichFaces 4+ don't support JSP(X) anymore as that's deprecated since JSF 2.0.

You've 2 options:

- Use `<jsp:xxx>` tags exclusively. It only doesn't support advanced templating.
- Use Facelets (XHTML) instead of JSP(X).

As JSP is deprecated since JSF 2.0 and succeeded by Facelets, the second option is obviously preferred. Don't forget to get rid of all `<jsp:xxx>` tags, or you will face the same problem from the other side on.

#### See also:

- [Why Facelets is preferred over JSP as the view definition language from JSF2.0 onwards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092161/why-facelets-is-preferred-over-jsp-as-the-view-definition-language-from-jsf2-0-o)
- [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets)