# Attribute "var" invalid for tag selectItems according to TLD

Tags: jsf

I'm working with h:selectOneMenu and want to set `label` and `value` for it then the UI option list will display `label` and in my Bean can get the selected `value`. I have this code working fine:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{myBean.selected}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.myList}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

But problem appear when I try to add var to set `label` and `value` by adding the code below:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{myBean.selected}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{myBean.myList}" var="field" 
    itemLabel="#{field.label}" itemValue="#{field.value}"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

The error show `Attribute var invalid for tag selectItems according to TLD`.

My question are:

Can I resolve this?

If "YES" then "HOW"?

If "NO" then any other way for me to done this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> *Attribute var invalid for tag selectItems according to TLD*

The `<f:selectItems var>` attribute was [introduced](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/selectItems.html) in JSF 2.0 for Facelets. This error suggests either you're using legacy JSF 1.x instead of the newer JSF 2.x where `<f:selectItems>` [lacks](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/javaserverfaces/1.2/docs/tlddocs/f/selectItems.html) the `var` attribute, or you're using legacy JSP instead of its successor Facelets as JSP is deprecated since JSF 2.0 and didn't get any of new JSF 2.0 tags/attributes. The exact error message is due to the JSP-specific term "TLD" however recognizable to come from JSP parser, which in turn confirms more that you're actually using JSP instead of Facelets.

In order to use `<f:selectItems var>`, you need to make sure of the following:

- You're using JSF 2.x instead of JSF 1.x.
- You're using Facelets instead of JSP.

If you can't upgrade/migrate, then you need to fall back to legacy [`SelectItem`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/faces/model/SelectItem.html) approach in backing bean. You can convert from your `List<Field>` to a `List<SelectItem>` as below:

```
private List<Field> fields;
private List<SelectItem> selectItems; // +getter

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    fields = yourFieldService.list();
    selectItems = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Field field : fields) {
        selectItems.add(new SelectItem(field.getValue(), field.getLabel()));
    }
}
```

```
<f:selectItems value="#{bean.selectItems}" />
```

#### See also:

- [Migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0)
- [Why Facelets is preferred over JSP as the view definition language from JSF2.0 onwards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13092161/why-facelets-is-preferred-over-jsp-as-the-view-definition-language-from-jsf2-0-o)
- [Our `selectOneMenu` wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/selectonemenu/info)